# python script thats always false

Tags: python

I ran my code today which is to tell if a user has nmap installed on Linux but when I tested it on a device that I know had nmap installed it would always come back as sorry nmap is not installed how can I fix this.

```
def isInstalled(name):
    cmd = """#!/bin/bash
    if ! [ -x "$#(command -v """ + name + """)" ]; then
      echo '0'
      exit 0
    fi"""
    ret = subprocess.check_output(cmd, shell=True).strip()
    if ret == b'0':
        return False
    return True
if isInstalled('nmap'):
    print("Nmap is installed")
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    s.connect(("8.8.8.8", 80))
    os.system('nmap ' +(s.getsockname()[0])+'/24 | tee NMAPSCAN.txt')
    os.path.abspath("NMAPSCAN.txt")

else:
    print("Nmap is not installed :(")
    os.system(sudo apt-get install nmap -y)
```

Comment: Does running just the `cmd` script in a terminal provide the expected response?

Comment: Is this being run from a central server?

Comment: Replace with `if ! [ -x "$(which """ + name + """)" ]; then`